# MongoServerError: cannot create a new collection already using 500 collections of 500, error code: 8000

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to insertOne more document in a new collection using this code:

```
await client.db(db).collection(newCollection).insertOne(newDocument);
```

However, this runs into error code 8000, which is not documented here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/error_codes.yml .

```
MongoServerError: cannot create a new collection -- already using 500 collections of 500
    at Connection.onMessage (/home/pi/projects/myProject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:210:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/home/pi/projects/myProject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at processIncomingData (/home/pi/projects/myProject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:132:20)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/pi/projects/myProject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:390:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:331:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:335:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

I did further research and found that number of collections one create is not limited by the user ("In general, try to limit your replica set to 10,000 collections") as stated here: [https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/schema-design-anti-pattern-massive-number-collections/#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20try%20to%20limit%20your%20replica%20set%20to%2010%2C000%20collections](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/schema-design-anti-pattern-massive-number-collections/#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20try%20to%20limit%20your%20replica%20set%20to%2010%2C000%20collections).

I am using Atlas on a shared cluster. Is this an Atlas issue or an issue with my code?

Comment: Just delete a database in Atlas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it's atlas M0 free restriction. See `Database and Collections` [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/?_ga=2.64883432.672284490.1656188568-609201914.1633727913#operational-limitations)